# TFS - Merging code out of the normal routine

Tags: merge

The typical process we use is:

1. Write code
2. Checkin changes with a description of what they are
3. merge forward (dev to QA)

We have been working on a series of changes. Management decided they want us to move up a small set of these changes.  These changes are all over the place.  I can't simply merge the changes by checkin/changeset as I normally do.

The only solution I can think of is to manually copy paste the changes I do want into QA.  This breaks my documentation and normal flow.  But, in the future the merge tool should pickup what has already been moved forward; that is when we revert back to the normal flow.

What would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, try to use [baseless merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy):

> Use baseless merge to merge items that are not directly branched from
>   each other. To perform a baseless merge, you must use the tf merge
>   command. When you perform a baseless merge, Team Foundation does not
>   have any information about the relationship of the files in the
>   braches. In a baseless merge, you must perform manual conflict
>   resolutions. After you have performed the baseless merge and resolved
>   any conflicts, Team Foundation records the merge history and
>   establishes a relationship between the folders and files.

[Improvements to baseless merge in TFS 2010 SP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/02/06/improvements-to-baseless-merge-in-tfs-2010-sp1.aspx)

Comment: +1 This does appear to solve the issue at hand and create a relationship (history).  I'll give it a go when we are ready to merge.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [WIMBI](http://www.sela.co.il/alm/products_Wimbi.html). What WIMBI does, is it merges by work items associated with the changeset(s).

What might work for you is to:

1. Associate the relevant changesets with a work item representing the unit of work (i.e. task) that needs to be ported (ideally, you would have done so when checking it in)
2. Create a *release* branch from your code from **before** the changes you need to merge (and before the changes you do **not** want to merge
3. Use WIMBI or cherry pick the changesets to perform the forward integrate your changes to the new release branch.

Hope this helps,
Assaf.